# Alterar style do overflow-y:scroll

Tags: css

Pessoal como faço para a barra ficar com fundo transparente e não branco igual na imagem abaixo:

Ja tentei

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-track

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Definir estilos para `scrollbar` é uma raridade, eles não são parte do padrão W3C para css, e portanto,a maioria dos navegadores simplesmente ignoram.

Porém existem `Webkits` que permitem a customização, em meus testes não consegui encontrar um que tivesse suporte a todos os navegadores atuais.

[Custom Scrollbars in Webkit](https://css-tricks.com/custom-scrollbars-in-webkit/)

No link acima possui um exemplo, o mesmo funcionará no Google Chrome, mas em outros
como Firefox e IE não farão efeito.

Procurei no `W3C` e encontrei o seguinte:

> Atualmente, Não existe nenhuma forma de customização do scroll compatível com todos os navegadores. [O artigo W3C](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/scrollbars.en.html)
>   Menciona no final a seguinte declaração em  sexta-feira 07 de agosto de 2015 18:50:04:

Alguns navegadores (IE,konqueror) suportam propriedades que não fazem parte do padrão como `scrollbar-shadow-color`, `scrollbar-track-color` e outras.
Essas propriedades são ilegais, elas não são definidas em qualquer especificação `CSS` nem são identificadas como propriétárias (prefixando-os com "-vendor-").

[W3C Scrollbars Test](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/scrollbars-test)

Neste topico no [StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9251354/css-customized-scroll-bar-in-div) e abordado esta questão e uma das abordagens mais assertivas e usar um plugin, Alguns deles:

[iScroll](http://www.jqueryrain.com/?zyslW0N2)

[nanoScrollerJS](http://jamesflorentino.github.io/nanoScrollerJS/)